# How to create a table with each rows easily clickable in Phonegap with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I want to create a table in Phonegap that has each rows with a small picture, name-all linked to another page. But having each rows just being an "a href" just creates a small skinny clickable area, which isn't that easy on a smartphone to click. How should I approach this issue? I also want it to be graphically appealing to some degree, I'm kind of lost on what I should be using here.

It's also important to note that since this is for Phonegap, not all html works the same way. Previously I tried a select list (with set id) and it works perfectly. It comes out as a nice list that I can select from. But on Phonegap this is not the case, this functionality is completely disabled and you can only use the normal drop down menu (even once enabled, it doesn't work). I have no doubt that this was placed in phonegap on purpose. There may be many other restrictions as well. Something that works in the browser != something that works the same on a smartphone.

I hope I was clear with my intentions here, please tell me if I need to provide more descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your DOM structure looks like, but, using jquery, you can attach a click event to each row.  If your just getting a thin area with an href, it may be due to your html structure. if you can post an example of that i'll update this answer. but you could use some css to give your href more padding and give it more of a clickable area.

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery mobile. http://jquerymobile.com/
As u can see in the docs it is exactly the thing u are looking for. I use it for the same use cases that u want, clickable rows with pics n info.

 works awesomely